# How to specify execution order of do block when using runhaskell?

Tags: haskell, runhaskell

Currently I'm trying to learn Haskell IO, and am using System.IO writeFile to edit a text file with this code:

```
main = do
 putStr "Enter Some Text: "
 text <- getLine
 writeFile "text.txt" text
 putStrLn "Updated!"
```

In ghci this works fine, but when I try to repeat it using runhaskell, it appears to run the 'text <- getLine' function first, and has the following output (first two lines were inputted):

```
runhaskell EditFile.hs
hello
Enter Some Text: Updated!
```

Why does runhaskell not run the function in order, and is there a way around this? (i.e. can I make it print "Enter Some Text: " before getting the user input?)